# Created my own Mac app bundle to run a shell script, displays correct icon in Finder but not in Dock

Tags: macos, icons, bundle

When I view my app bundle (it runs a shell script) in the Finder, it shows the correct icon, from the bundle > Contents > Resources > AppIcon.icns file.

I created that file as follows:

- Downloaded an SVG file that I wanted to use
- Used GIMP to create 16x16, 32x32, 64x64, 128x128, 256x256, and 512x512 png files
- Used iconutil command to create the AppIcon.icns file
- View it in Preview to ensure it shows the same sort of display when opening AppStore icons file

I found in the Finder I had to duplicate my folder structure to get the icon to show (apparently very common).

When I drag it to the dock, I get a weird icon I've never seen before. It's not the circle with line through it that means can't run this app.

It looks kind of like a sewing mat:

- 3 vertical and 3 horizontal lines in a grid
- 2 diagonal lines connecting corners at 45 degree angles
- 1 large circle that touches the edges
- 2 smaller concentric circles in the center

Anyone have any idea why it shows this way in the dock, or how I can fix it? It runs correctly (the purpose is to launch a QEMU ArchLinux ARM VM if you're curious).

My Mac is an M1 with Monterey, just bought it about 2 weeks ago.

Here is my info.plist file contents, maybe it missing some required keys or something:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>Arch Linux</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>me.bantling.ArchLinux</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string>AppIcon</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconName</key>
    <string>AppIcon</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: What CFBundleIdentifier did you give it in its Info.plist file? Is it possible there's a conflict, and it's inheriting the icon from something else with the same ID?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my bundle was just fine. It was solved when I created a new VM (for reasons unrelated to this issue), copied the bundle to the new dir, and replaced the bundle in the dock with the new one.

The icon showed the same as the Finder. There were also some reboots in between putting the original app in the dock and the new one.